# can't install mysql on openshift 4 online realse

Tags: mysql, openshift

I am trying to install mysql image on openshift 4 online using developer catalog , unfortunately , no mysql image on the catalog's list.Where can i find the mysql image and how can i install it?

This is for openshift 4 online release,the process was simple with openshift 3 online .

Comment: The OpenShift Online Starter 4 experience is still being improved. You should be able to launch myself with `oc new-app mysql` until it's available in the catalog.

Comment: Thanks Will for the quick reply . I'm faced with a problem , while i was trying to execute the [oc] command. i couldnt find the oc login command which is necessary to login to my account .could you please help.

Comment: Depending on your cluster, it should be available at `https://openshift-authentication-openshift-authentication.apps.<region>.online-starter.openshift.com/oauth/token/request`